# How to read third-party console logs dynamically in code

Tags: java, logging, reflection

I'm writing a Java app that uses a third-party library; this library emits useful warning messages to the console when things go wrong.  So useful, in fact, that I'd like my code to act on them *at the time they are produced* (or shortly afterwards).  Is this possible given the fact that I have no control over how the third-party library's logs are produced?

My best Googling has turned [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/10806851877/) up so far, which looks promising; but I don't know anything about `PrintStream` or whether the third-party library uses it for logging.

Is there some sort of equivalent to reflection whereby an application can process its own logs?

Comment: You'll get more useful answers if you explain how this library produces log messages.

Comment: Learn about PrintStreams before even thinking about doing reflection.
Reflection is not the answer here, anyhow.

Comment: @tgdavies - I have no idea how it produces log messages!  That's the point; it's a black box to me.  They just appear in the console when I run my `.jar` file.  I include them as `logger`s in my `log4j2` configuration file.

Comment: @tgdavies - slf4j/logback may well provide an answer, or at least a route to be explored: thank you!